# indexing code documentation sites (sphinx, postgres full-text, xapian...?)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, sphinx, information-retrieval, xapian

I was wondering which of the indexing libraries out there would
be suitable for a site of code documentation where you can't just
ignore "punctuation" as insignificant.   (In some of the
languages I'm interested in, punctuation can be part of
significant "words", like some standard method names in Raku such as
"^methods", "^mro", etc.)

Full unicode/utf-8 support is also important, but I suspect
that's a given in modern packages.

Answer (score 1):

Manticore Search would be suitable since:

- it supports [low-level tokenization](https://manual.manticoresearch.com/Creating_an_index/NLP_and_tokenization/Low-level_tokenization) fine-tuning which is important for `can't just ignore "punctuation" as insignificant`
- searchdcode.com [uses Manticore Search as a backend](https://twitter.com/boyter/status/1313266512690438145) which proves it can work in your case too